# PHP intended as css but served as MIME type text/html

Tags: php, css, mime-types

I have some forms in webpage. The forms are generated by a CMS component. The styling of the forms is set through a template_css.php file, which facilitates the dynamic styling given a form's variables.

In my local environment, the file is loaded fine, and the css renders as expected. But in public server, the css is not rendered and I get the following warning from Chrome debugger:

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: ...filepath

What can I do to force this file to be read as CSS even though is a PHP file?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to set the header to text/css:

`<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your public server is specifying the mime type for php files. If apache see [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html%20mod_mime) for details.